# char array corruption in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, char, cout

I'm working on a project that makes me store an array of objects whose constructor is

```
Item(char* item, int itemType){
char temp[200];
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        temp[i] = '\0';
        if(item[i] != '\0'){
            temp[i] = item[i];
        }
    }
    _item = item;
    _itemType = itemType;
    _tweetIDs = NULL;
}
```

Don't worry about _tweetIDs, that's another functional part of my program and isn't related to my problem.

This array is stored within a class:

```
ItemList()
```

How this works is that the functional part of my program parses a line of input and puts it into the Item(char*, int) object. This is how it adds the line:

```
int addItem(char* item, int type){
    char temp1[200];
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        temp1[i] = '\0';
    }
    int j = 0;
    while(item[j] != '\0'){
        temp1[j] = item[j];
        j++;
    }
    _items[_size] = Item(temp1, type);
    _size++;
    return _size;
}
```

Where _items is the Item() array and _size is a field that is incremented every time an Item() is added.

My issue comes when I have to print the contents of the list.

I have a method that does that:

```
void printList(){

    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        if(_items[i] != NULL){
            cout << "[" << i << "] ";
        _items[i]->printContents();
        }
    }
}
```

I tested printContents() in the constructor of Item() and tested printList in the addItem method and they both work when called within the class itself. The issue comes when I have to call the print method outside the class body.

In the main method, I create a List object:

```
List itemList;
```

The default constructor sets all members of the Item() array to NULL and initializes _size.

After adding a few Item() objects into the array (Which I confirmed is increasing in size through the debugger), I tried to print it out. When I call:

```
itemList.printList();
```

It gives me the right amount of indexes (And lines), but the char array is just a bunch of garbage. I used the debugger to try and find out where it went wrong. In the addItem() method, I called printList to check the array, and the output from that is fine. Then, I called itemList.printList() right after the last addItem() call, and it gave me garbage. In between the addItem() and itemList.printList(), the char array is lost or something along those lines.

Any idea what's going wrong? I'll give you any more code if you need it.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `memcpy(_item, item, 200);` and declare `_item` as `char _item[200]` in class declaration, so that it will live longer than the instance of constructor.

Comment: @ruslik I put the temp arrays into my class fields and it works great now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/2509). It will save you some surprises later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Item` constructor, you are setting what I presume is a member `_item` as such:

```
_item = item;
```

This just assigns the pointer value of the location pointed to by `item` into `_item`.  It does not actually copy the string!

The next time you go to read this location, it might be valid - chances are, though, it will be garbage, as you are seeing.

What you are looking for is a function like [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) (as a side note, there's no need to do quite so much manual copying - just pass that pointer around and copy it once - in the `Item` constructor).

**EDIT**, to address your comment:

`strcpy` made your program crash because you are using it on unallocated memory.

You have to allocate memory for an array using [`new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new%5b%5d/) in c++

Comment: strcpy made my program crash every time I used it. I also tried manually copying the char array, but that didn't help.'

Comment: You'll need to *allocate* the memory before you `strcpy()` into it. Why don't you use the `string` and `list` classes from the standard library?

Comment: I'm only allowed to use iostream and cstring.

Comment: @Johnsyweb - c++ has a standard library?  I thought it was just c with classes ;^)

Comment: @SkylineAddict: If you have such a restriction, you should state it (and the reason for it) in your question.

Comment: @Nate: It seems the OP's professor is under a similar misconception.

Comment: My professor is one who enjoys doing things from scratch (And making his students do so). But, I fixed the issue. I kept my manual copying, the only thing I had to change was putting the temporary char arrays into the fields of the classes, just to change the scope. After that, it works fine.

Comment: @SkylineAddict: I suspect (hope) that your professor purely wants you to understand how to do things from first principles. Just as long as you know not to re-invent wheels when you start work!

Answer (score 1):

Take note on the lifetime of a variable.
If you declare *temp1* as static array, then it will be destroyed immediately by the end of function *addItem*.

At the end, all object that refers to this memory location will be invalid.

And ....
If you want to pass a reference to an array do it this way:

```
Item(char** item, int itemType)
```

Comment: The lifetime was the main issue. Putting my temp arrays in the field of the class and not declaring it in the function fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `Item` constructor you create local array `char temp[200]`, you copy there what is pointed by `char * item` and then you don't use `temp[200]` any more. What's the point of doing that?

Later you assign passed pointer to `_item` member. The pointer points to local variable `char temp1[200]` in `addItem()`. When `addItem()` finishes then `temp1` is destroyed and so `_item` in `Item` class points to garbage.

What you probably need to do is to allocate memory either statically in `_item` definition or dynamically using `new` (and then not forget to release it). I think the first solution will be safer for you. In the latter case you would also have to take care of copy constructor and assign operator. So, you need to change `_item` definition from `char * _item` to `char _item[200]`, and then you can use `strncpy`:

```
Item(char* item, int itemType) {
    strncpy(_item, item, 200);
}
```

Comment: The way I did it was pretty much exactly what my professor wanted me to do. The only difference is, he wanted me to use strcpy to do the copying and not manually. I found strcpy to be more bothersome to me than helpful so I ended up not using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining your definition of class Item minimally looks like this:

```
class Item
{
Item(char* item, int itemType);
private:
    char *_item;
};
```

Your constructor must allocate memory for _item in order to make a copy of what gets passed in via the constructor. Failure to do that will inevitable result in memory problems and exceptions. Alternatively, you can use something like a vector of char.